# $\times$ versus $\otimes$ in Definition of $K$-Algebra

Tags: hopf-algebras, algebras, coalgebras

While reading about algebras and coalgebras, I keep coming across two definitions of an algebra $A$. One definition uses the Cartesian product $\times$, while another uses the tensor product $\otimes$. (The definition for a coalgebra always uses $\otimes$.) Both definitions are ones involving commutativity of diagrams.

When should $\times$ be used, and when should $\otimes$ be used? Is the reason for $\otimes$ due to the $K$-linearity of the underlying maps (where $K$ is a field), while we do not require $K$-linearity for the definition involving $\times$? I suppose I'm trying to make sense of which definition should use $\times$ (and why) and which should use $\otimes$. Could someone please explain these two variations to me?

Comment: For two $k$-vector spaces take a basis $A = \sum_j k a_j,B = \sum_i k b_i$ then $A \times B = \sum_i k (a_j,0)+ \sum_i k (0,b_i)$ whereas $A \otimes_k B = \sum_{i,j} k \ a_j \otimes_k b_i$ where $a_j \otimes_k b_i$ is a bilinear symbol indicating a pair. For $k$-algebras the multiplications are defined by $(a_i,0)(a_n,0)= (a_ia_n,0), (a_i\otimes_k b_j)(a_n\otimes_k b_l)=a_ia_n\otimes_k b_jb_l$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal property of the tensor product of vector spaces says
$$\text{Hom}_{K}(A\otimes B,C)\cong\text{Bil}_{K}(A,B;C)$$
so in the case that $A=B=C$, this means that *bilinear* functions
$$C\times C \to C$$
are in one-to-one correspondence with *linear* functions
$$C\otimes C \to C$$
so in the definition of an algebra you can ask for any of those, but as I said they are completely equivalent.

In the case of a coalgebra, you can only talk about a linear function
$$C\to C\otimes C$$
since there is no equivalent way to say this in terms of $\times$.

Comment: Oh, so it makes sense to stick with $\otimes$ when defining both algebras and coalgebras; otherwise, if you use $\times$ when defining an algebra but $\otimes$ when defining a coalgebra, it will simply confuse the reader (and not emphasize how we are "dualizing" to go from the notion of an algebra to that of a coalgebra). Is that correct?

Comment: @BrittK Yes, that is right :). Usually people use bilinear functions out of $C\times C$ because defining the tensor product and its universal property just to talk about algebras might be overkill.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of it that way, but that makes sense.